# LWIP CGI handler - Sending data back to webpage instead of returning a filename

Tags: cgi, stm32, iot, stm32f4, lwip

I'm running an LWIP http webserver on an STM32F4 discovery board. It displays a webpage when its IP address is entered on a web broswer. I need to send a string back to the webpage when the LWIP CGI handler is called. The javascript code in the html page is expecting this. how do I do that? The only thing I can send to the web page is a URL to another local html page.

here is the setup:
the project was created using the STM32 cubeIDE. Its using the LWIP stack with FreeRTOS. This web page sends a CGI command to the stm32 board using the http GET method. Then LWIP CGI handler is automatically called and executes. I can retrieve the data sent by the webpage.

This is the what the CGI handler looks like:

```
const char *my_cgi_handler(int iIndex, int iNumParams, char *pcParam[],
                             char *pcValue[])
{
    //do some stuff with retrieved data

    // return a filename
    return "/index.html";

}
```

[here is a simple LWIP CGI example code](https://github.com/particle-iot/lwip/blob/master/contrib/examples/httpd/cgi_example/cgi_example.c)

This handler does not give the socket descriptor so that I can directly send data to the web page. [Also The LWIP documentation says I should not write directly to the web page.](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__httpd.html)

> The simple CGI support offered here works with GET method requests
> only and can handle up to 16 parameters encoded into the URI. The
> handler function may not write directly to the HTTP output but must
> return a filename that the HTTP server will send to the browser as a
> response to the incoming CGI request.

How will I solve this problem without editing the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lwIP SSI (Server-Side Includes) for this. See documentation on [configuration #define switches](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__httpd__opts.html#gacb70e0cdd30a940f8bce681c6cc63949). [The HTTP server documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__httpd.html) has some information on SSI, and there's also some [SSI example code](https://github.com/particle-iot/lwip/blob/master/contrib/examples/httpd/ssi_example/ssi_example.c).

Basically,

- #define LWIP_HTTPD_SSI in your configuration header
- add a file to the lwIP HTTP server which only contains `/*#TagName*/`
- register a callback with http_set_ssi_handler. This callback will be called when a http client requests the new file. The callback will receive information about the tag and you can write an arbitrary answer to a supplied buffer. By default, the response is limited to LWIP_HTTPD_MAX_TAG_INSERT_LEN bytes. If that's not sufficient, you can #define LWIP_HTTPD_SSI_MULTIPART to make longer responses.