# LWIP CGI handler how to post data to webpage as JSON

Tags: embedded, webserver, cgi, stm32, lwip

LWIP CGI on STM32 web server application cgi callback is receiving on CGI handler properly but the handler return the html page tag name , instead of that how could we send a requested data from web the cgi handler is as below

```
const char *CGIsetting_Handler(int iIndex, int iNumParams, char *pcParam[], char *pcValue[])
{
    if (iIndex == 1)
    {

    }

    return "/index.html";
}
```

Instead of this how send a data the html
webpage is expecting data as below

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        document.getElementById("infoDesc").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText).Description;
        document.getElementById("infoSerial").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText).Serial_Number;
        document.getElementById("infoTag").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText).Device_Tag;
        document.getElementById("infoContact").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText).Contact;
        document.getElementById("infoVersion").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText).Firmware_Version;
      } else {
        console.log("response ", this.status);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getSystemSettings.cgi", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71293965/583044

Comment: Actually that is same query from my colleague . the situation is we cant change the html page we have keep the same format as above and give a proper json data back from cgi handle

Answer (score 0):

On `const char *CGIsetting_Handler(int iIndex, int iNumParams, char *pcParam[], char *pcValue[])` 
you can return like

```
return "/logList.json";
```

But then you should provide some data in

```
int fs_open_custom(struct fs_file *file, const char *name){
if (!strcmp(name, "/logList.json")) {
memset(file, 0, sizeof(struct fs_file));
file->pextension = (void *)&generated_logfile;
if (file->pextension != NULL)
{
  int result;
  result = generate_json_logfile(file);
  if (result < 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  // 0 - 404
  // 1 - 200
  return 1;}}}
```

In my case generate_json_logfile is static char buffer which filled with formatted output. If you put correct json data in that buffer it would be enough for browser.

Comment: I have tried editing the handle call back by passing connection callback pcb , the return write the data back to webpage using tcp_write() function . it is working but not proper some time hit hard_fault . what will be the maximum size of data can be write with this function ? Also when running this the cgi handle not returning proper html page instead calling tcp_write that may also course for the httpd api to crash